# Marginal distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, density-function, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

A loss distribution has PDF - $f(x) = 1/x^2$, for $x > 1$
An insurer finds that the time in hours it takes to process a loss amount x has a uniform distribution on the interval $(\sqrt x, 2\sqrt x)$. Find the expected time to process a claim of random amount.
Can anyone please explain how to put the limits of integral.  Find it a little confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be the RV representing the time. Given $X$, we know that $Y$ is uniform with mean $E[Y|X]=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{X}$. Using the [law of total expectation](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), 
$$E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]]=\frac{3}{2}E[\sqrt{X}]$$
which you can find easily with the marginal distribution of $X$.

**Edit** I don't recommend this way, but it's good practice for you to verify. Here is the marginal PDF of $Y$, going forward from my *comment* below: 
$$f(y)=\int_1^\infty f(x,y)dx=\int_1^\infty \mathbb I(\sqrt x\leq y\leq 2\sqrt x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{x^2} dx=\int_{y^2/4}^{y^2} x^{-3/2}dx$$

Comment: I wanted to know the integration method and how to put the limits. Will be grateful if you can explain in detail

Comment: You'll take integral for $E[\sqrt X]=\int_1^\infty \sqrt x f(x)dx$

Comment: I mean from the joint distribution, how to get the marginal distribution of y.

Comment: $$f(y)=\int_{1}^\infty f(x,y)dx$$ But this is the longer way.

Comment: No unfortunately this is not the answer... that’s where I needed help

Comment: It says first integrate from 1 to y^2 and add y^2/ 4 to y^2

Comment: I don't follow you. Do you want to calculate the expected value from the joint distribution, or do you want to calculate the marginal of $y$ from the joint distribution as you've said in your previous comment?

Comment: First the marginal of y, and thereby the e(y); as the question asks

Comment: @SundareshSubramanian does it answer your question?

Comment: In the solution they have integrated the joint PDF from y^4 to y^2 and added that to joint PDF integrated from 1 to y-2

Comment: why dont you put your solution and we investigate where you don’t understand? clearly, although might be correct, you are not interested in any other method.